# Changes tracking for detached entities or session per client?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I develop a server with persistent client connections (non request based). As I keep track of each connected client state in memory it would be strange if I load entities each time when I need to access such client data.

So I have my detached entities and when I need to perform any changes I don't apply them directly but instead pass these changes and detached entity as a request to GameDb class. It performs changes on this entity and than loads the same entity from the db to perform the same changes again on session-owned entity so NH can track these changes.

I could use Merge but it's much slower because NH should load all entity data (including lazy collections which could be unmodified) to check each property for changes. In my case the performance **is** critical.

An example:

```
    public void GameDb.UpdateTradeOperation(UserOperation operation, int incomeQuantity, decimal price)
    {
        if (operation == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("operation");
        if (operation.Id == 0) throw new ArgumentException("operation is not persisted");
        _operationLogic.UpdateTradeOperation(operation, incomeQuantity, price);

        try
        {
            _factory.Execute(
                s =>
                {
                    var op = s.Get<UserOperation>(operation.Id);
                    _operationLogic.UpdateTradeOperation(op, incomeQuantity, price);

                    if (op.User.BalanceFrozen != operation.User.BalanceFrozen)
                        throw new Exception("Inconsistent balance");
                }); // commits transaction if no exceptions thrown
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new UserStateCorruptedException(operation.User, null, e);
        }
    }
```

This approach brings some overcomplexity as I need to apply each change twice and check if the result states are equal. It would be easier if I could use NH Session to monitor entity changes. But it's not recommended to keep NH session opened for a long time and I could have thousands of such long lived opened sessions.

Also it forces me to split my entities and common logic. The problem is that GameDb class doesn't know from which context it's called and can't request any additional data for its operation (e.g. current prices or client socket inactivety timer or many other things) or it may need to conditionaly (by its decision) send some data to the client. Of course I can pass a bunch of delegates to GameDb method but it doesn't seem to me as a good solution.

Can I use Session.Lock to attach my unchanged detached entities so I don't need to perform the changes twice? What LockMode should I use?

Can I use a better approach here? If I keep one opened session per client but commit or rollback transactions quickly will it still open a lot of connections? Will the session keep entities state after the transaction is completed?

What kind of concurrency issues I can experience with long lived per-client-sessions:

1. If I operate each user entities only from **its own** thread fiber (or lock)?
2. If I request another user profile for readonly from "wrong" session (from that session's thread)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to use Session.Lock (LockMode.None) to reattach detached entities to the new session and it works. It adds an object to the session as clean and unchanged. I can modify it and it will be stored to the database with the next transaction commit.

This is better than merge because Nhibernate does not need to look at all the properties to find out what is changed.

if I change at least one property it updates the whole object (I mean all the properties but without collections and entity links if they are not touched). I set DynamicUpdate = true in the entities mapping and now it updates only changed properties.

If I change **any** property of the dettached entity outside of its current session, the next call to Session.Lock throws an exception (especially if I change the collection content the exception states "reassociated object has dirty collection"). I do those changes outside of the session because I don't need to save them (some stuff with references).

Very strange, but it works perfectly when I call Lock twice!

```
try
{
    s.Lock(DbEntity, LockMode.None); // throws
}
catch
{
    s.Lock(DbEntity, LockMode.None); // everything ok
}
```

Also for collections: before I came to the solution above I casted them to IPersistentCollection and used ClearDirty().

What about concurrency? My code unsures that each thread fiber updates only its user and nobody except this fiber has write access to the entity.

So the pattern is:

1. I open a session, get an entity and store it somewhere in the memory.
2. When I need to read its property - I can do it at any time and very fast.
3. When I want to modify it I open a new session and perform Lock() on it. After applying changes I commit the transaction and close the session.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to do is to use a second level cache, and store Id of entities per connected client instead of storing entities in the memory.

When client connects you can fetch the entities using Id you storing, which will not even hit the database in subsequent requests as it will fetch entities from the second level cache and you do not need to worry about change tracking.

http://ayende.com/blog/3976/nhibernate-2nd-level-cache

Comment: This is a **real time** server. It may use entity state very often, may be ten times per second. For an example, it may "move" that client in 3D space and the movement speed is a constant which is stored inside that client entity. You say - copy that value once? I have a lot of them! And they are perfectly stored in client entity now. Hibernate cache is fast but Dictionary is faster but objects in memory are much faster.

Comment: If you use the second level cache you can scale your solution by adding more servers, however if the second level cache is not good enough I would say you might have to create a queue where it stores the operations and once every period (say 60 seconds) it merge the changes and write in one go. Disadvantage is you will know if there is an error only after one minute in worst case.

Comment: It's better to update only entities that you changed and when you do it. See my own answer.